# Unexpected token 'hypervisor' in expression or statement

Tags: windows

I recently installed Microsoft Hyper-V Server V. 10.0.17763 on my HP Proliant DL380 G7 and the installed the windows admin center on my computer. When i was trying to start the VM in the Windows Admin Center this error showed up:

```
Unexpected token 'hypervisor' in expression or statement.

 At line:3 char:102
 + ... ossibile impostare il tipo di utilità di pianificazione dell'hypervis ...
 + ~ The hash literal was incomplete.

 At line:135 char:64
 + SmeSubmit -vmIds (cvt '["43014470-7064-4c73-9b5d-544f6ed3fd2e"]')
 + ~~ The string is missing the terminator: '.

 At line:1 char:30
 + function Import-LocalizedData{$script:strings=@{
 + ~ Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition
```

I have no idea why this error is showing up but i can tell you more. The virtual machine i'm trying to run has the virtual disk in the default HyperV folder and the installation iso into the default HyperV folder as well

Answer (score 0):

--> SOLUTION <--

Apparently the italian language is doing something bad with the powershell syntax, i changed the language to english and now everything is working